# Does Fischer esterification occur when mixing alcoholic drinks with lemon juice?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, esters, carboxylic-acids

I would assume it does happen because the ethanol in the drink would be in an acidic environment because of the lemon juice and would react with the citric acid in it. But the thing is, how come we don't notice the formation of this ester when we drink, let's say, vodka mixed with lemon? Is it because the concentration is just too low for actually tasting it?
I have already searched some properties of the product of the reaction between ethanol and citric acid and found out it is odorless and colorless, but didn't find anything about its taste.

Comment: Beside kinetics considerations... Odour is, by the way, a very important part of what commonly we refer to as "taste". For the rest looks at the concentration of the reactants.

Answer (score 1):

A mix of alcohol and acid with some acidity given time will reach an equilibrium of alcohol, ester, water and acid. At the pH levels and concentrations of a vodka martini with a twist it might take a long time but it will happen.  The question is how long do you wait before you drink it.  This is an important factor in wine production and why wine changes with age.  http://www.diwinetaste.com/dwt/en2007066.php
If water is removed esterification is a reasonably fast reaction taking minutes to hours for completion, but if water is in excess or acid is low I can imagine it requiring months to years for equilibrium.